# BigCommerce Local Stencil Development Footer Scripts Not Loading

Tags: footer, bigcommerce

On developing a stencil theme locally, I noticed that {{{ footer.scripts }}} do not load any scripts that are located in the Footer Scripts section under Storefront. Is there any way for the footer scripts to be loaded when working locally?

Comment: At this time the Stencil CLI does not fetch footer scripts when working locally.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about what are you trying to achieve by accessing footer.scripts locally? is it to test logic from a script? or any other thing?

Comment: I'm trying to test a third party script that I keep in footer scripts in production for a theme I'm developing locally. The script is used for one of our third party apps that adds information to customers. I can place the script in the local theme and it works, but there doesn't seem to be a way to automate the retrieval of the footer scripts from production for local theme development.